# How come Django templates, Ajax, and form.errors don't work together in a more integrated fashion?

Tags: django, ajax, django-views, django-templates

I'm continuing on my Django, Ajax, and form.errors journey...and here's what I can and can't make sense of....If an ajax request submitted by django....has form.errors....how come django can't recognize this in the template?  It can if the form is submitted via a traditional form_valid approach...but not as_json.  If the error is as_json....you have to manually interrogate the errors.  At least this is the most documented method on the internet.  Can someone who is way smarter than I am provide a reasonable explanation as to why this wouldn't be possible?  It seems like it should be....with just a simple template loop...

Instead I've read the way to solve this is ajax with crispy forms...or ajax with manipulating the DOM.  Thanks in advance for any feedback on this topic.

Comment: I think it does. But you have to use djangorestframework. Django isn't built-in for handling JSON data by default.

Comment: @Awishka Dambawinna Thanks for the feedback.  Will put on my list of things to try to validate in the near future.